# Fs.writeFile error when trying to write to json file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord Bot command where my bit stores different text entries in a json file, but everytime I try to test it I get this error: "TypeError: fs.writefile is not a function".
Is there a different way to do this and/or is there something in my code I can improve to make this function correctly?

```
module.exports = {
    checkInData: function(msg) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const bot = new Discord.Client();
        const PREFIX = 'sick.';
        const fs = require("fs")
        bot.entries = require('./entrydata.json')
        let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch(args[0]){
            case 'entry':
              editedmsg = msg.content.slice(17);

              bot.entries [args[1]] = {
                message: editedmsg
              }
              const configD = JSON.stringify (bot.entries, null, 4)
              fs.writefile ("./entrydata.json", configD, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
                msg.channel.send('message written');
              });

            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `fs.writeFile(...)`, functions are case-sensitive

Comment: Thank you, I'm an idiot and overlooked that somehow.

Comment: You're welcome! I make that mistake all the time too

Answer (score 0):

It' supposed to be `writeFile` not `writefile` (lowercase `f`)  as seen in the doc

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback